# A method for extracting a random segment of characters from a string?

Tags: ruby

Example string is:

```
str = "WZMLYZDVBTAAJJ2T21CWIA"
```

To get the first or last 5 characters, I can do:

```
str.first(5)
 #=> "WZMLY" 
str.last(5)
 #=> "1CWIA"
```

Strangely `str.center(5)` returns the entire `str` (no error)? What's up with that?

Is their like a `random(5)` method which would do something like `str[4..9]`? I know I can obviously do the following: (which always assumes my str > 9 chars)

```
random = rand(5)
random_str_segment = str[random..(random+5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in method.

```
random = rand(str.length - 5)
random_str_segment = str[random..(random+5)]
```

Oh, and the `center` method returns the string centered in whitespace:

```
"abc".center(10)
=> "   abc    "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.slice(rand(str.size - 5), 5)
```

Also, read the documentation for `center`:

> Centers str in width. If width is greater than the length of str, returns a new String of length width with str centered and padded with padstr; **otherwise, returns str**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is this:

```
a = "WZMLYZDVBTAAJJ2T21CWIA"
a[rand(a.size-5), 5]
```